# WebViewer (apryse/ pdftron) annotations sample - is not working on node js

Tags: node.js, angular, pdftron

As i tried to run this node js sample (https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-annotations-nodejs-sample) provided by PDFTron(apryse) get errors pls help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALp3f.png)

This is a WebViewer sample to show how you can save and load annotations through files with Node.js backend.
but its not running pls help if anyone know about this how to run.

yes, I tried(re-install NPM)
Now it starts loading but the main save function is not working. Did you know what the problem is?

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1103288408262062174/1106488708728897557/image.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1103288408262062174/1106488708980547684/image.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1103288408262062174/1106488709232201758/image.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1103288408262062174/1106488709471289354/image.png

whenever I tried to put the annotation the save button is not working.

even inside the XFDF folder, no files are saved.

can you pls help me with this how it will work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the `npm install` again, and in the end you should see message like `WebViewer files copied over successfully`.